# INSERTing rows from a SELECT statement into a sequence of columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, insert, split

This maybe a bit of a noob question, but is there a nice simple way of inserting `ROWS` from a select statment into `COLUMNS` of another table?

I'm not just talking about doing an `INSERT / SELECT`.

I have a function which splits some CSV into rows. So say I have two rows of data like this

```
joe,bloggs,joe.bloggs@domain.fake;jane,soap,jane.soap@domain.notreal;
```

I split first by semi-colon, then by comma

Result of first split call

```
Id Data
1  joe,bloggs,joe.bloggs@domain.fake
2  jane,soap,jane.soap@domain.notreal
```

The on each of these I run the split function again

```
Id Data
1  Joe 
2  Bloggs
3  joe.bloggs@domain.fake
```

With this returned data, I want to do an insert statement that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO Customers (@first,@last,@email) 
SELECT [row1].[col2],[row2].[col2],[row3].[col2]
```

Is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: are you using SQL Server database ?

Comment: usr, thanks for the spartan reply. It pointed me in the right direction at least

Comment: Last execution of a split function to give us the result in a single column, but the INSERT statement uses three columns. Could you clarify that step, please?

Comment: Thanks alexander, I fixed that. Should have been col2 in every case of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way load all the data from CSV to database table is to use [`BULK INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx) statement. All you need to do is to use correct parameters(in your case FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = ';')

```
BULK INSERT Customers
FROM 'c:\split.csv'
WITH
(FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
 ROWTERMINATOR = ';'
 )
GO
```

After the first splitting you have a data in table format. Thus you can use greate method of splitting a column with delimited string into multiple columns using XML method

```
INSERT dbo.Customers([first], [last], [email])
SELECT Split.a.value('/M[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS [first],
       Split.a.value('/M[2]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS [last],
       Split.a.value('/M[3]', 'VARCHAR(100)' ) AS [email]
FROM (SELECT CAST('<M>' + REPLACE(Data , ',' , '</M><M>' ) + '</M>' AS XML) AS xmlData
      FROM dbo.testCSV
      ) AS x CROSS APPLY XMLDATA.nodes('.') AS Split(a)
```

Demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/55ab2/2)

Comment: Hi Alexander. I can't do it this way. My data is not coming from a CSV file.

Comment: "I have a function which splits some CSV into rows." Mind == blown.

Comment: I should have explained that the Comma Separated Values are not stored in a .csv file. They're coming from another source. It doesn't really matter - I decided to go the variable route afterall.

Comment: @roryok answer was renovated, please try again

Comment: Thanks alexander. I decided to go with static variables since my structure doesn't change, but this does answer the original question so I'll accept it